# malloc and gcc optimization

Tags: c, optimization, allocation

I've written some memory allocation code in c as an exercise. It is translated almost purely to macro now. By doing this I've been able to reduce allocation time to something similar to glibc malloc (unoptimized). However, running the test with gcc -Ox where x > 0, I can't get anywhere near glibc's speed -- glibc beats me by around 10^2

I understand that the glibc malloc implementation is based on Doug Lea's dlmalloc and the comments suggest the code does benefit from optimizing compilers. I haven't looked into why this is and I am not clued up on compiler optimization tricks and was wondering if anybody knew or could give a hint on what techniques are commonly used?

Comment: The problem is almost certainly not the compiler options but your design. You should always aim to make your algorithms efficient first, and wait to do low-level optimizations until you have a solid, well-performing design.

Comment: The fact is that the code performs well when not optimized. It is only outperformed when optimizing flags are applied. This says to me the code simply needs to be "groomed" for the optimizer. I in no way suggest a problem with the compiler.

Comment: Were you compiled with debug in the first test?

Comment: What was the test? It may be that your allocation code is slow both ways, but your test code is written in such a way so that there was a more dominant bottleneck without optimizations that disappeared with optimizations.

Comment: @jxh not possible. the difference in testing glibc malloc and my allocator is a change to a single line. ie the test is literally a single line of code timed with the unix time utility.