# malloc and gcc optimization 2

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, optimization

```
while(count < 30000000){
    malloc(24);
    count++;
}
```

the above code runs in about 170 ms on my computer compiled with gcc -O0. However, compiling with -Ox where x > 0, the optimizer cleverly figures out that the memory being requested will never be used and so it is excluded from the optimized executable. How does it do this?

Comment: What does `2` mean in the title? it's not clear.

Comment: @YuHao they referred to [their previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848426/malloc-and-gcc-optimization)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well the compiler sees `malloc` return value is never used so it optimizes it out. If you want to prevent `malloc` call to be optimzed out even in `-O3` you can use the `volatile` qualifier:

```
while(count < 30000000){
    void * volatile p = malloc(24);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and work around. That's really great. Does that mean that the compiler has knowledge of the malloc symbol? I don't see how else it could be done. I mean, if you wrote your own allocator, could you induce the same behaviour?

Comment: @user2616927 the optimizer knows `malloc` and considers it is a function with no side-effects.

Comment: Yes, you can use the [`pure` or `const` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)to allow the optimizer to make similar optimizations regarding your own functions.

Comment: @Carl Norum How did you find that out?

Comment: right, I see from the manual it's used for side effect free functions. Well done. Thanks.

Comment: @user2616927 You could select the answer if you like it ;-)